# How to Create a Full responsive asp.net page with rdlc report viewer

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

**This is my Site please have a look.**
http://accstatus-lkl2.mfgbd.net:58995/D15.aspx

**What I Want :**

The content to fit according to the screen size with no scroll bar.

**What I tried :**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  ReportViewer1.AsyncRendering = False And ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = True
  ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage
End Sub
```